# Eloquent: Update on multiple records of pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

These are the records in my `user_office`

- userID: 1, officeID: 1
- userID: 1, officeID: 2

When I send a new POST request for updating the user's office, ie
`{userID: 1, offices:[{3,4}]}`
I would like to update the rows into the `user_office` table, such as to have these records:

- userID: 1, officeID: 3
- userID: 1, officeID: 4

What I am currently doing is basically deleting manually first all the rows with:
`$this->eloquentUser->destroy($userID);`
and then inserting the new values with: 
`$this->eloquentUser->create(...)`

I am pretty positive that there is a cleaner way to do this, so please feel free to share your thougths.

**Update** Don't ask why,but I am using Laravel 4.2. :)

Comment: Why don't you try `sync`? [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: @linuxartisan That looks quite clean solution that -to be fair- I was not aware of . Need to amend my code and give it a go.